# Setting google plus snippet info via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm looking to share things on google plus but I need to be able to populate the snippet info myself as the pages I am sharing are loaded via ajax on my jquery mobile site.

So that being said I need to set the info either via the url (facebook sharer style) or via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to just go ahead and use the schema.org in my situation. This worked because when you view one of my pages is "promoted" to the first page in the list of cached pages. So even if you were to start on page A and browse to page B and then share page B when google searched the url you have provided page B is now before page A and thus is schema.org meta data is used.

I have no doubts that writing your own redirect page and passing it some thing like this

```
?redirect_url=http://google.com&img=your_image.jpg&description=its great&title=a product
```

would work. The only thing to remember is that you will need to use a javascript redirect that way when google looks at the page it see's the page and does not get redirected (bots dont use js) but when a person hits the page it will redirect them to the real page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the rich snippet that appears, you should use the [snippet tool](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/) to create schema.org that is then placed on your site. The share link would then be that page, which would contain the attributes set to how you want them to appear. You can specify the title, the image, and the description for the content that gets shared.

If you are trying to just create a link to share something, you can create direct links to the share dialog. For example,

```
<a href="plus.google.com/share?url={your url}">Click to share</a>
```

will create a share link to {your url}.

Because jQuery mobile is rendering a lot of the information on the actual client, you might need to generate a URL, similar to the one above, that would then point to another page that would with the right content in schema and a redirect to your site. When they follow the share link, a user would be redirected to the jQuery mobile page. When Google reached the page you're redirecting from, it would read the schema.org markup and correctly calculate the snippet. The following example works for me:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <head>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Example">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the most awesome thing ever.">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://placekitten.com/250/250">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>window.location='http://istoocute.com/#kittens';</script>
    <a href='http://istoocute.com/#kittens'>Click here if you're not redirected</a>
    There's really nothing to see here, move along...
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/250" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that each page on jquery mobile page contains multiple pages. This is used for caching and even by default just to handle animations. So unless google is smart and will only use schema.org info that is visible and not hidden then that wont work.

Comment: Got it, so your pages are rendered client-side? The answer suggesting hashes could work, however, if that doesn't work, you could create a redirect page that takes parameters and outputs schema based on those parameters. When Google+ calculates the snippet, it would just serve the description and markup from your redirect page.  When a user follows the link, they would get redirected to the anchor in your jQuery mobile site.

Comment: That might also be a possibility. Hopefully google will catch on and make it work similar to how the facebook sharer url works as that is ideal for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#configuration - shows you the configuration settings that you need.

Comment: Based on the info here for populating the snippet it does not look like there is any way to populate the snippet with the data by hand. Which is a problem due to the fact that jquery mobile has multiple "pages" per traditional page.

Comment: Well how is your jQuery mobile pages setup? are they by hashtag? Looks like you could do gapi.plusone.render({href:<pageaddress>#hash});